# Why does array have max size 2 ^ 32 -1 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

Max native integer value in JavaScript is `2 ^ 31 - 1 = 2147483647`

You could check it using the following code:

```
let x = 2147483647;
console.log(x << 1) // you will get -2 instead of 2,147,483,647 * 2 = 4,294,967,296
```

It means that variable bigger than `2 ^ 31 - 1 = 2147483647`, always has floating point type.

But according to the [ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#array-index) max array size is `2 ^ 32 - 1 = 4294967295`.

So if I write something like

```
let size = 3000000000;       // float type
let array = new Array(size); // passing float variable to constructor
                             // that accepts integer only
```

It means that firstly `size` will have float type, and then we pass this float size as array size argument. But array size obviously must be integer.

And it does not have any sense at all.

So the question is: Why does ECMAScript says that max array size is `2 ^ 32 - 1` and not `2 ^ 31 - 1`?

Comment: considering that in js there's no discerning between integer and floating point, being both hold by the number type, I can guess that maybe that's the biggest size of an array because it's the biggest integer number you can represent with 32 bit by the engine interpreting the code. By the way as stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ... Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991; // Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;

Comment: What is the relationship between the "max native integer value" and the "max array size"? What is a "max native integer value"? "But array size obviously must be integer." Why? You are making multiple assumptions in your question and I can't follow.

Comment: @jabaa they are wrong. The first assumption was based on a shift but as stated in my comment the biggest safe integer that could hold in a number type variable is way above that one: 2^53. The approach to get there, as you said, also is wrong because there's no correlation between the logic steps. And since 2^32-1 is the max 32bit unsigned number, it just makes sense with no further analysis.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita as I could confirm by digging through the sources of spidermonkey and v8, it just checks for uint32 boundaries and sets indice above uint32 to a string hash representation. just go through my answer to see my summary.

Answer (score 4):

## Tl;dr:

#### It casts from double to uint32, that's why 2^32-1 works and is usable from within js without any issues.

---

It is in fact possible to create a holey array with exactly up to 2^32 -1 numerical slots. anything beyond will be converted to a string hash index and will not iterate the array length property beyond 2^32 -1.

one way would be this:

```c
# node
Welcome to Node.js v16.15.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const a = new Array(2**31-1)
undefined
> a
[ <2147483647 empty items> ]
> a.push("foo", "bar", "asdf")
2147483650
> a
[ <2147483647 empty items>, 'foo', 'bar', 'asdf' ]
> a.length
2147483650
> a.length = 2**32 -2
4294967294
> a.push("magic", "beer", "such overflow")
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
    at Array.push (<anonymous>)
> a[2**32]
'such overflow'
> a[2**32 -20] = "indexable beyond 2^31-1"
'indexable beyond 2^31-1'
> a
[
  <2147483647 empty items>,
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'asdf',
  <2147483626 empty items>,
  'indexable beyond 2^31-1',
  <17 empty items>,
  'magic',
  '4294967295': 'beer',
  '4294967296': 'such overflow'
]
> a.length
4294967295
```

another example without initial length:

```c
# node
Welcome to Node.js v16.15.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const a = []
undefined
> a[2**32 -10] = "magic"
'magic'
> a[2**33] = "overflow"
'overflow'
> a
[ <4294967286 empty items>, 'magic', '8589934592': 'overflow' ]
>
> Object.keys(a)
[ '4294967286', '8589934592' ]
> a[5] = "foo"
'foo'
> Object.keys(a)
[ '5', '4294967286', '8589934592' ]
> a
[
  <5 empty items>,
  'foo',
  <4294967280 empty items>,
  'magic',
  '8589934592': 'overflow'
]
> a.length
4294967287
```

but if you fill it, you will run out of heap memory:

```c
# node
Welcome to Node.js v16.15.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const a = [];
undefined
> a.length = 2**32 -1;
4294967295
> a.fill(0)

<--- Last few GCs --->
n [1537688:0x5818540]    33577 ms: Mark-sweep 238.5 (256.1) -> 238.3 (272.1) MB, 202.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.4 ms in 42 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 833 ms) (average mu = 0.971, current mu = 0.868) allocation f[1537688:0x5818540]    52935 ms: Mark-sweep 1796.1 (1833.3) -> 1796.1 (1833.3) MB, 1996.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 3.3 ms in 235 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 9982 ms) (average mu = 0.911, current mu = 0.897) alloc

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa1c193 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xcf8dbe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xcf9137 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xeb09d5  [node]
 6: 0x10dcbdd  [node]
 7: 0x10dcdb3 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary> v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary>, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
 8: 0x10dd3f4 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary> v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::Add<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, v8::internal::InternalIndex*) [node]
 9: 0x1005348  [node]
10: 0x108b615 v8::internal::JSObject::AddDataElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes) [node]
11: 0x10cf36e v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin) [node]
12: 0x10d3903 v8::internal::Object::SetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>) [node]
13: 0xd5972d v8::internal::Builtin_ArrayPrototypeFill(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
14: 0x15f2179  [node]
[1]    1537688 abort (core dumped)  node
node  26,77s user 21,04s system 39% cpu 2:02,24 total
```

You can also initialize an Array with up to 2^32 -1 items:

nodejs:

```c
> new Array(2**32-1)
[ <4294967295 empty items> ]
> Array(2**32-1)
[ <4294967295 empty items> ]
> 3000000000
3000000000
> Array(3000000000)
[ <3000000000 empty items> ]
```

firefox:

```c
Array(2**32-1)
(4294967295) [empty × 4294967295]
new Array(2**32-1)
(4294967295) [empty × 4294967295]
```

Your question was quite a bit misleading since you made it appear, as if anything beyond 2^31 was simply impossible to access while the spec explicitely states to convert the argument (IF it is of Number type) to uint32, thus allowing you to use a float to reach beyond 2^31 for indexing.

fact:
https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-array
[image: specification for Array(...values)]

[image: specification for 10.4.2.2 ArrayCreate ( length [ , proto ] )]

So in essence, the engine converts your `Number` to uint32.
since IEE 754 (JavaScripts floating point type) can carry numbers beyond 2^32-1, it will simply convert it.

It does a static cast to uint32 as seen in v8:
https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/b5283a2e5bc31b254a73f2a0e59841a8654de092/src/builtins/builtins-array.cc#L176-L178

```c
// Set "length" property, has "fast-path" for JSArrays.
// Returns Nothing if something went wrong.
V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeHandle<Object> SetLengthProperty(
    Isolate* isolate, Handle<JSReceiver> receiver, double length) {
  if (receiver->IsJSArray()) {
    Handle<JSArray> array = Handle<JSArray>::cast(receiver);
    if (!JSArray::HasReadOnlyLength(array)) {
      DCHECK_LE(length, kMaxUInt32);
      MAYBE_RETURN_NULL(
          JSArray::SetLength(array, static_cast<uint32_t>(length)));
      return receiver;
    }
  }

  return Object::SetProperty(
      isolate, receiver, isolate->factory()->length_string(),
      isolate->factory()->NewNumber(length), StoreOrigin::kMaybeKeyed,
      Just(ShouldThrow::kThrowOnError));
}
```

Same with Spidermonkey:
https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/32ca4fc265150e7d3d7aa6c6abea088768cf024b/js/src/builtin/Array.cpp#672

```c
// Step 3.
if (!ToUint32(cx, desc.value(), &newLen)) {
  return false;
}
```

## So the answer to your question is:

#### The Array uses uint32 internally in Spec (even in 5.0) and both SpiderMonkey and V8.

### It casts from double to uint32, that's why 2^32-1 works and is usable from within js without any issues.

Comment: When I pass 300000000 to array constructor it is `Number`, not a `BigInt`, since  call with `BigInt` would be `new Array(3000000000n)`. Moreover in older ECMAScript revisions way before BigInt, array max size was the same `2 ^32 -1`. So your answer is incorrect.

Comment: To be more precise: When I pass `300000000` to array constructor it is `Number`, not a `BigInt`, since  call with `BigInt` would be `new Array(3000000000n)` And this code not even work, try it yourself. Moreover in older ECMAScript revisions way before `BigInt`, array max size was the same i.e. `2 ^ 32 -1`. So your answer is incorrect.

Comment: there you go. edited.

Comment: small side note: there was a time computers could only efficiently work with signed integers. javascript still runs on such machines.

Comment: I found the answer. And you will be surprised that all you wrote have no meaning behind this reasoning. I will answer by my own

Comment: @NoNameQA there you go. your assumption of inaccessibility was wrong.

Comment: @NoNameQA still waiting for your "surprising" answer you promised.

Comment: @NoNameQA still waiting..

Comment: @NoNameQA the wait isn't over :D

Answer (score 2):

> Why does array have max size `2^32 - 1` in JavaScript?

Quite simply: because it's specified that way. The specification authors could have chosen any maximum value.

`2^32 - 1` is the biggest value that can be represented in an unsigned 32-bit integer. This is a reasonable choice because it limits required memory for storing an array length to 32 bits while maximizing the lengths that can be stored in these 32 bits.

A JavaScript engine could therefore theoretically use an unsigned 32-bit integer to store any array length (and, by extension, any valid array index). I don't know whether any JavaScript engines actually do it that way. (V8 doesn't; it uses either a signed 31-bit(!) integer or a IEE 754 float64, because... reasons too long to explain here!)

> Max native integer value in JavaScript is `2 ^ 31 - 1 = 2147483647`. Variable bigger than `2 ^ 31 - 1 = 2147483647`, always has floating point type.

No, all Numbers in JavaScript are specified to be IEE 754 64-bit floating point values, there is no such thing as a "max native integer value" in JS. *Some operations* (namely, the bitwise operations like `x << 1`) convert their inputs to signed 32-bit integers. FWIW, *unsigned* right-shift converts its input to unsigned 32-bit integers and interprets its output as that too, hence e.g. `(-1 >>> 0) === 4294967295`. This observable behavior doesn't guarantee anything about how the engine chooses to represent these values on the machine level. There is no way to tell whether `1` or `2147483647` is being stored as an integer or a float inside the engine. The JavaScript spec only guarantees that it'll *behave* like a float.
And, to tie this back to the question, what bitwise operations do is totally unrelated to the maximum array length.

Comment: @NoNameQA Please read the second paragraph again, which explains why `2^32 - 1` is a reasonable choice. Using the maximum int32, as you suggest, is no more consistent or logical than using the maximum uint32. -- This question has nothing to do with V8, I'll remove the tag.